# marginpar only left

Tags: marginpar

I would like to have marginpars only in one side of the document, say, left; independently of the two-side option in `documentclass` or of the styles like `amsart`, `book` etc. I was attempting to do this by modifying Ex. 14.28 in Knuth's book but command works not so nice. Sometime I've got tiny vertical stirrings of lines in a paragraph when I insert/remove the new command like `\doMarginLeft{note text}`. The purpose of this excersise is a need not of the actual remarks on marginfileds in printed document but wish for a possibility to make some temporary notes while working with document. Something like interline remarks for myself. So, since people do read left to right I want to watch on my screen the marks strictly on left or in center, say. Is it possible all this?

Addendum. Here is an example which works for me.

`\def\DoMarginLeft#1{\strut\vadjust{\raisebox{2.5ex}[0mm][0mm]{%
\fontsize{5pt}{0mm}\usefont{T2A}{cmr}{m}{ui}{#1}}}}`

This is a rather reduced version of Knuth's Ex. 14.28

`\def\strutdepth{\dp\strutbox}
\def\marginalstar{\strut\vadjust{\kern-\strutdepth\specialstar}}
\def\specialstar{\vtop to \strutdepth{
\baselineskip\strutdepth \vss\llap{* }\null}}`

Knuth inserts here just a star symbol on left and my command does the similar task except that arbitrary tiny font text line has been positioned between lines on (strictly!) left side of the current line and paragraph. As I pointed out above such a construction is not robust. Depending on circumstance, when I remove command `\DoMarginLeft{...}` (or Knuth's command) some lines of the current paragraph may stir vertically; that's not good for me. I want to have the same effect without visual moving the lines. And this should be independent of class options, two-side option, or other LaTeX settings.

And follow up, I would like to use preferablу a light command but it is not desirable to use an extra package. Surely there is no way apply the internal LaTex means to solve such a toy problem?

Comment: As always on this site, it is a lot easier to help if you provide some code that others can cope and test as is.

Comment: Why do you want to use `twoside` option then?

Comment: You should look at the todonotes package.  There is also \llap.

Comment: I added some more explanations to the question.